# SimpleMembershipProvider creating odd table names

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, security, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

So I really don't care the table names created by SimpleMemberProvider when the table names are something like "webpages_UsersInRoles". 
*However* I do have a problem when it creates tables with names like "DOMAIN\user.webpages_UsersInRoles".

I kid you not this is happening.
Does anyone know what is causing this??

Background Info:
I am working with IIS Express with Visual Studio 2012. This particular project is using EF5 and MVC4 with Migrations Enabled.

The SimpleMembership tables are being created when I start up the web-app via

`WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);`

within the default `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` given to you by MVC4.

I hope that's enough info but if it's not let me know and I can provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that the user connecting to SQL Server has a Scheme associated with it. When manually adding a table 'table_1' inside SQL Management Studio the table name became DOMAIN\user.table_1.